# Sqlite3 Transaction Logic

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I am completely lost with Sqlite3 transactions in node.js

When does this opens and closes db object exactly? I tried different versions with `db.run("COMMIT");`  `db.run("END");`  BEGIN and so on however it did not work. I also did not get the logic behind it.

Can someone explain me how can I fix this, I'll take this as an example to fix others as well.

```
router.post("/analizUpdate",function(req, res){


    db.serialize(function(){

        db.run("DELETE FROM analizIcerik where analizIsmi=?", req.body.analizIsmi, function(e){

            if(e){

                res.send("problem when deleting"); 

            }

        });

    for (var i=0; i<req.body.length; ++i){
    var optcount = i + 1;
    var sutunA=req.body['A'+optcount];
    var sutunB=req.body['B'+optcount];
    var sutunC=req.body['C'+optcount];
    var sutunD=req.body['D'+optcount];
    var sutunE=req.body['E'+optcount];
    var sutunF=req.body['F'+optcount];   

   db.run("INSERT INTO AnalizIcerik (analizIsmi,analizTipi,sarfiyat,sonuc,ideal_deger,ilave_deger,ifElse,order2) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", req.body.analizIsmi,sutunA,sutunB,sutunC,sutunD,sutunE,sutunF,optcount,function(e){

       if(e){

           res.send("update problem");

       }
   });

    }

   });  

    res.render("success.ejs");
});
```

Comment: Please update your question and explain what you're trying to do and what result you're currently getting. "it did not work" isn't useful.

Comment: According to https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3-transactions, transactions don't really work without additional software.